# Solution to a quadratic diophantine

Tags: diophantine-equations

Given $b,d,e,M\in\Bbb Z$ how can we solve for $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that 
$$by+xd+xy e=M?$$

Comment: Where's the quadratic?

Comment: $\alpha\gamma$ variable

Comment: Basically, you are asking for integer points along a rotated hyperbola.